# Enable a disabled button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

So, I have a button that 's disabled by default on form load and I'd like to enable it when all conditions evaluate to TRUE.

```
private void OnFormLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BtnInvoice.IsEnabled = false;
    }
 private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(A.Text, "^[a-zA-Z' ]*$") && Regex.IsMatch(B.Text, "^[0-9.]*$") && Regex.IsMatch(C.Text, "^[0-9.]*$"))
        {
         BtnInvoice.IsEnabled = true;
        }
```

In the above code, when all conditions evaluate to TRUE, my button remains disabled.
I'm pretty sure I put the enabling block in the wrong place may also have a logic error.

Comment: Did you check with a debugger if the code is run or not and how the regexes match or not?

Comment: Did you do any debugging? If so, does it enter the if statement or not?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Code has no errors also regExes evaluate to TRUE

Comment: @BlakeThingstad the IF statement checks the conditions only when the button is pressed but... it's disabled!

Comment: Try first without using the if statement + conditions. Is your Btn_Click handler actually called? Is BtnInvoice.IsEnabled = true; actually doing something? Only if this is working, include the if conditions and see if it is still working. Use the debugger. Set breakpoints. etc... etc...

Comment: @elgonzo commenting the "onFormLoad" method and the IF statement the button works.
Obviously, if I de-comment the method the button goes off.

Comment: Jim, *you* need to troubleshoot your problem. Step-by-step simplify your program until the problem does not occur anymore. Then, again step-by-step reintroduce parts of the code again, until you hit a step where the program begins exhibiting the problem again. Hone in on the problem. Nobody except you can see your source code of your program, nobody except you can debug your source code, nobody except you can see how your running program behaves exactly. I am sorry, but from what you have told us so far it is not possible to derive a meaningful assumption about the cause of your problem.

Comment: Also, you said your problem is with **enabling** the button. Your problem is not with disabling buttons, correct? So why are you now playing around with the OnFormLoad method? It is not trying to enable any button, right? Stay concentrated and focus!

Comment: "the IF statement checks the conditions only when the button is pressed but... it's disabled!" - if you want to enable the button when the button is clicked then how could you ever expect the code to run if its disabled from the start?

Comment: @BlakeThingstad in the case I described in the question the IF statement is inside the button method whilst it doesn't need to be necessarily there. What I need is the minute the user inputs the 3rd value the button to turn ON. So, possibly I need something more than the IF statement.

Comment: In that case... lets say the input is a TextBox. Subscribe to the TextChanged event and put the if statement and enabling in there.

Comment: What is the Text in A, B and C?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd TxtBox1, TxtBox2 and TxtBox3

Answer (score 0):

In situations that I must determine when a button needs to be enabled or not, I prefer implement a Command on that button. The CanExecute on the command holds the logic whether the button is actually enabled or not.

See http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/commands/using-commands.